# Where is the Path of Android Plugin and the corresponding Build tool?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Where exactly is the path of the Android Plugin?

and dependency :
**com.android.tools.build:gradle:a.b.c ( say 3.1.3 or 2.2.2)**

My guess is the dependency and Android Plugin version should be same.

Comment: Gradle plugins will be downloaded by Gradle. Where Gradle stores its downloaded files varies by Gradle version. It is usually rooted in `~/.gradle` (and the Windows equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

> path belong to the project level gradle and dpendency belong to the app level gradel,
>   this is project level gradle where you can find class path 
>   [image]
>
> yes plugin an dependency should be same becase plugin is a jar file that execute the task and dependency is a jar that provides the class files to execute the task.

Comment: I mean where in PC they can copied or installed?

Comment: gradle belong to every project separately, go on app , right clicl , and show on explorer. there you can see your gradle file.